# How to avoid "Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended" warning during debug with Java 11?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classloader, java-11

Recently I switched to the Java 11 and start to debug my app and saw this message:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot
>   loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

Found only [this commit](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/18fba780c1d1) and [ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8203031), but it doesn't tell me much.

Do I need to worry about it?

Comment: You are trying to use -Xbootclasspath/a and CDS (or AppCDS) at the same time. Can you run with -Xshare:off to disable CDS?

Comment: Just a guess(since I saw something similar), you're using an IDE that's doing what Alan pointed out without you even being aware of it? Is that IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, this is IntelliJ

Comment: Same problem in IntelliJ IDEA with Java 12.

Comment: This happened to me right after I switched to java 12, I did run with -Xshare:off and it worked fine too but What exactly this does, Could it be preventing something that I will need in future or anything bad might happen?

Comment: can someone elaborate on this? Why it is happening and what is -Xbootclasspath/a and/or CDS (or AppCDS)?

Comment: Using JDK 13, @zarez' solution works for me whereas disabling instrumenting agent doesn't

Comment: I have the same issue when running unit tests in IntelliJ IDEA, not only when debugging.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I had this issue too after installing `jdk-12.0.1_windows-x64_bin.zip` when trying to use the debugger with IntelliJ IDEA. I was getting an error of (**Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended**). I found, too, going into Setting and search for async and unchecking the Instrumenting agent box. Worked for me!
[image: ASYNC settings]

Comment: Before you turn this off, read about the Async Stack Traces feature to see if it might not be useful for you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/async-stacktraces.html

Comment: In a nutshell: When a parent thread starts a child thread or process (certain 'capture points'), a thread dump is made. When you break in the child thread, part of it's stack trace will be from the parent thread.

Comment: How to disable the same settings on CI without GUI interface?

Comment: Without GUI you can disable it by option `-Xshare:off` for VM.

Comment: How can I fix this issue on Bitrise?

Comment: I get this warning when I use "@SpringBootTest". After unchecking "Instrumenting agent", I still get the warning.

Answer (score 44):

You can ignore this warning. It just means that class data sharing is disabled for classes not loaded by the bootstrap class loader.

From [Improve Launch Times […] With Application Class-Data Sharing](https://nipafx.dev/java-application-class-data-sharing/):

> The JVM loads some of the JDK classes with the bootstrap class loader
> and the rest with the system class loader, but includes all of them in
> its default archive. When IntelliJ executes your project, it tells the
> JVM to load some code with the bootstrap class loader by appending to
> that class path (second part of the message). Now, that means that the
> portion of the archive that contains classes loaded by the system
> class loader is potentially invalidated and so the JVM partially
> deactivates sharing (first part of the message).

You could disable class data sharing completely with `-Xshare:off`, but this may increase the launch time.

Comment: I get this warning when [instrumenting my code with Azure Monitor Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#quickstart), ie. when adding `-javaagent:path/to/applicationinsights-agent-3.0.3.jar` to my application's JVM args. Adding `-Xshare:off` gets rid of the warning (changing IntelliJ settings does NOT). Thanks!

Comment: Using Gradle, the CLI still produced them. Adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xshare:off` to `gradle.properties` resolved most of them.  However, I also had to modify the test tasks by adding `test { jvmArgs "-Xshare:off"; /* ... */ }` to the tests (Junit 5) in order to remove them entirely from the command line.

Comment: So is this bad English "... is only supported because ..." implies that it is accidentally supported, but by the sound of things it should say "is only supported for classes appended to the bootstrap classpath". Is that correct?

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue after installing Java12 when trying to use the debugger with Intellij Idea. The solution that I found was to go into Setting and searching for async and unchecking the Instrumenting agent box.

Answer (score 14):

For me, the issue occurred only when I ran in Docker, and when I used a java command line agent like the DataDog APM agent (`-javaagent:/dd-java-agent.jar`).
When I ran in my JDK11 runtime environment (without the agent) I did not get the warnings.

Comment: I know this is years later, but if you download a newer version of the dd-java-agent jar this error goes away

Comment: I'm still having issues with Bitrise. How can I fix it?

Comment: Yup, same experience from me: this started appearing when adding the DataDog java agent.

Answer (score 9):

Given this warning in IntelliJ is harmless (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57957031/779173) you could just hide the line from your Console view by right-clicking on the line and selecting "Fold Lines Like This"

Having done this, you'll just see:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe" ... <1 internal line>
```

Answer (score 4):

For Intellij IDE -> Settings/Preferences dialog ( Ctrl+Alt+S ), go to Build | Execution | Deployment | Debugger | Async -> uncheck instrumenting agent

Comment: Duplicate answer

Answer (score 2):

[image: Operation guide]

1.Open the **Preferences** option;

2.Find the **Build,Execution,Deployment** option;

3.Enter the **Debugger --> Async Stack Traces** ;

4.Uncheck the **Instrumenting agent(requires debugger restart)** ;

---

Please see this [for detailed information](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/async-stacktraces.html).

Answer (score 0):

If it is not critical you can change your jdk version. I've changed from jdk14 to jdk 11. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: For my case I am using Java 11 but was accidentally on jdk14, so this helped! To change: File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem, and tried to solve it as was written above.

But then i got another solution of problem without changing settings.

Press mouse right button on your file where you put break point and want to debug. Then choose "Debug *ur file name.method()*".

Don't use debug button from tools window. Seems the problem is that Idea can't understand which file u want to debug.

That worked for me without changing async settings.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfi0A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using gradle, you can turn sharing off:

```
tasks.test {
    //kotlin
    jvmArgs = listOf("-Xshare:off")
    //groovy
    jvmArgs "-Xshare:off'";
}
```

Answer (score -9):

Java version must be 9 or higher.

[image]

Answer (score -9):

Today I found the same question as you.
Situation: debug while set no breakpoint
Solution: set at least one breakpoint before you click debug button!