# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

The error message I got while trying to debug my code

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended"

[image]

What does it mean, why do I get it and how to get rid of it?

Comment: This is an issue with hotspot and not your code as such. It may be that you're running on a newer version of Java than your version of IntelliJ is expecting/supporting, in which case, the answer is to upgrade your IntelliJ version or degrade your Java version.

Comment: It is not working yet.

Comment: What did you do? What was your version of Java and Intellij before, what is it now? Please be precise.

Comment: [Gabriel García Muñoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9812545) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66216314) saying ""This question is related to this one, check it out and let me know ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205486/how-to-avoid-sharing-is-only-supported-for-boot-loader-classes-because-bootstra"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid "Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended" warning during debug with Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205486/how-to-avoid-sharing-is-only-supported-for-boot-loader-classes-because-bootstra)

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this warning.

You can just include `-Xshare:off` in the VM options of the code editor configurations.

Eg:

In IntelliJ:

Run/Debug Configurations -> Edit configuration template (bottom left) -> add VM options `-Xshare:off`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but it can helps others out there!!!

as the warning is specifying the bootstrap class path is appended, To Smash the warning follow these simple steps.

Click on File Menu>Settings,
On Search Text Area on the left, type Async Stack Trace, Click on it in the options to open

UnCheck Instrument Agent,
Click Apply then Ok.

Comment: No that did not work for me. But my error might come from known issue with mockito see> https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2590