# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended error

Tags: java

Whenever I try to use the debugger in IntelliJ this error pops up and it opens up the java file FileInputStream. I found this ticket [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65613084/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-sharing-is-only-supported-for-boot-lo) but changing the async setting didn't work for me. I'm running java and JDK version 15.0.2. I haven't updated my java or IntelliJ at all recently but this error started showin up anyways

Comment: I did some debugging and if I click resume something like 20 times eventually the debugger goes back to the proper place and does the debugging properly

Comment: When I uncheck async stack traces I don't get the error anymore but IntelliJ still opens multiple files that I have to skip through for me to reach the debugger

Comment: Nevermind I was being an idiot, java was being programmed to treat any exception as a breakpoint for some reason