# Problems with running the test in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a petService class where it lists pets from a shelter and imports the pet file where it gets the id or name of the shelter through the Java class's Scanner and the name of the .csv file also through the Scanner. Then I created a test for importing pets, when running it gives me an error saying that it was not possible to find a line for the scanner.

I used the Junit and Mockito libraries to create the tests.

The ImportPets code:

```
public void importarPetsDoAbrigo() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Digite o id ou nome do abrigo:");
        String idOuNome = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite o nome do arquivo CSV:");
        String nomeArquivo = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nomeArquivo));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao carregar o arquivo: " +nomeArquivo);
        }
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] campos = line.split(",");
            String tipo = campos[0].toUpperCase();
            String nome = campos[1];
            String raca = campos[2];
            int idade = Integer.parseInt(campos[3]);
            String cor = campos[4];
            Float peso = Float.parseFloat(campos[5]);

            Pet pet = new Pet(raca, nome, tipo, cor, idade, peso);

            String uri = "http://localhost:8080/abrigos/" + idOuNome + "/pets";
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.dispararRequisicaoPost(uri, pet);
            int statusCode = response.statusCode();
            String responseBody = response.body();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                System.out.println("Pet cadastrado com sucesso: " + nome);
            } else if (statusCode == 404) {
                System.out.println("Id ou nome do abrigo não encontado!");
                break;
            } else if (statusCode == 400 || statusCode == 500) {
                System.out.println("Erro ao cadastrar o pet: " + nome);
                System.out.println(responseBody);
                break;
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }
```

The test code:

```
@Test
    public void deveVerificarSeImportouOsPetsDoAbrigo() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String userInput = String.format("Test%spets.csv", System.lineSeparator());
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(userInput.getBytes());
        System.setIn(bais);

        when(client.dispararRequisicaoPost(anyString(), any())).thenReturn(response);
        petsService.importarPetsDoAbrigo();
        verify(client.dispararRequisicaoPost(anyString(), anyString()), atLeast(1));
    }
```

The error generated:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
Digite o id ou nome do abrigo:
Digite o nome do arquivo CSV:

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1656)
    at br.com.alura.service.PetsService.importarPetsDoAbrigo(PetsService.java:57)
    at br.com.alura.service.PetsServiceTest.deveVerificarSeImportouOsPetsDoAbrigo(PetsServiceTest.java:31)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

I performed the debugging and managed to identify that the first scanner was performed successfully but the second was not. I've tried to do some things but I couldn't.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This looks like a problem people had after upgrading Java versions in IntelliJ IDEA.  Are you using that IDE?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205486/how-to-avoid-sharing-is-only-supported-for-boot-loader-classes-because-bootstra

Comment: I suspect it is related to using multiple Scanners on the same input stream (i.e. System.in).

Comment: The code requests 2 inputs with the Scanner, but in the test I am using only one input.
I tried to duplicate the input code but it didn't work the same way.

Comment: In general, consider using `Console.readLine` to prompt for user input rather than the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error!

I managed to solve it simply by changing the code in the petsService class.

I changed the scanner code to:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite o id ou nome do abrigo:");
    String idOuNome = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Digite o nome do arquivo CSV:");
    String nomeArquivo = scanner.nextLine();

    scanner.close();
```

The previous code was:

```
    System.out.println("Digite o id ou nome do abrigo:");
    String idOuNome = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    System.out.println("Digite o nome do arquivo CSV:");
    String nomeArquivo = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

Apparently this was what generated the error of not finding the second line of the input.

Thank you all for your help!